# Why can Detours no longer hook shell32.dll functions in Windows 7+

Tags: windows, detours, shell32

In Windows XP it was possible to hook explorer with the following shell32 hook:

```
Real_SHFileOperation = (T_SHFileOperation) DetourFindFunction("shell32.dll", "SHFileOperationW");
nError = DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)Real_SHFileOperation, Detoured_SHFileOperation); 
if(nError != NO_ERROR)
{
    TRACE_ERROR(g_hTrace, "DetourAttach SHFileOperation Failed (%d)", nError);
}
```

For some reason on Windows 7 this no longer works even though DetourAttach still returns success.  All the other hooks that I install (in ntdll.dll for example) still work but the hooks I've created in shell32.dll no longer do.

I attached Windbg to the explorer and ran `uf shell32!SHFileOperationW` this showed that the function did indeed now jump to my function:

```
SHELL32!SHFileOperationW:
76239708 e9039658fc      jmp     myhook!Detoured_SHFileOperation (727c2d10)
```

However, somehow explorer skips right past my detour and into other parts of the SHFileOperation function....

Comment: The fact the detour is attached and it still jumps to your function implies the issue is something inside rather than outside your function, does it not?

Comment: If I put a break point in my function it never trips...  so no I don't think so.  Even if I do something trivial in there such as an OutputDebugString, it never prints.  And yet despite this I can see explorer entering the real function in procmon...

Answer (score 1):

Hmm,

It appears that what I really should be doing on Windows 7 is hooking the IFileOperation interface:

http://stuani.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/ifileoperation-hook-under-vistaseven.html

Looks trickier than simple detours hooking but achievable.